# Android's best approach for precise timed events handling

Tags: android, events, handler, precision, timed

I´m trying to improve my events handling system to make it more robust, improving precision stability.

Since the it´s a time based event handling/answering system, the first relevant decision would be which time reference to use. After reading everything I could find I ended up using SystemClock.elapsedRealtime().
Why not to use SystemClock.uptimeMillis() or System.nanoTime()? Because my system needs to keep working while in sleep/screen is off.

Any better approach here?

After that, the most problematic step: how to handle the timed events and guarantee they happen at desired time, without lags/delays/variations?

After reading as much as I could I decided to go for the handler approach, having one of them for each class of event (so different classes can happen asynchronously).

Unfortunately this isn´t working as expected:
- The timming sometimes gets perfectly synchonized and sometimes gets really big constant delays. without changing the code at all, just launching the application minutes after. Any clock synchronization issues between threads (event generator and event handler are in different threads)?
- The handler timming isn´t constant/precise and I can easely notice event results being displayed out of sync with a variable lag.

Any tips about how to handle timed events in a more precise way in Android?

Thanks,
Gabriel Simões

Comment: Since your application is one of many running, this type of precision won't be able to happen, especially in the background.

Comment: So, in the end the conclusion is that things like synchronizing audio and UI isn´t possible at all on Android? I still believe it can be done, at least with a much better precision than the one in my approach.

Comment: Hi, I have been able to synchronize but after sometime the same app gets out of synch once again. If I force stop the app and relaunch it, the synchronization becomes perfect once again. No idea of what it may be...